# DeprecationWarning: 'root' is deprecated, use 'global'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on project and stuck at a point where i got this error

```
unexpected token at '(node:14500) [DEP0016] DeprecationWarning: 'root' is deprecated, use 'global'
```

because I have used JavaScript tag at the end of the view file.

Moreover if I use application JavaScript file instead of admin/admin then it works fine but i need to use admin layout script file. [image]

So how can I fix this issue ?

Comment: It seems that the issue is somewhere inside JS files. I'd check there

Comment: @mrzasa So how can I check issue in js file??

Comment: Do you have anything in server logs?

Comment: @mrzasa I have working on a local system not on a server.

Comment: I assume you run a rails application so you start a local server (`rails s`) and access a web page via browser, where the error is shown, right? Could you check server logs and see if there is an error there?