# unexpected token at '(node:7103) DeprecationWarning: 'root' is deprecated, use 'global' '

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I am working on a ruby on rails project and when I have add some coffee-script in haml view file then it gives error. I am wondering from last day why this happening

```
784: unexpected token at '(node:7486) [DEP0016] DeprecationWarning: 'root' is deprecated, use 'global'
```

coffee-script code

```
:coffeescript
  $ ->
    $('#chaperone').click (event) ->
      console.log('testing')
```

If i have remove this code from haml view file then it works fine but what is wrong with this code?? how can i fix it??

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54036700/deprecationwarning-root-is-deprecated-use-global, neither have answers yet

Comment: @JaredBeck No!!!! yet not receive any answer.